# Deploy Maven project with integrated Tomcat

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat, jar, web-deployment

I've researched many resources how to deploy Maven project to jar file and then to tomcat. So my question: is it possible to integrate tomcat server to my maven project and then deploy it to jar file, because I want to launch my web application just by double clicking on the jar file.

Comment: As you are using Spring, want to use Tomcat and use maven. Instead of cobling something together yourself I suggest you move your application to [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) which provided this out-of-the-box for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin. Add to your `pom.xml` the following lines:

```
 <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Source: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/

After that you can start your web application via command line:

`mvn tomcat7:start`

> I want to launch my web application just by double clicking on the jar file.

This solution doesn't allow you to run web application just by double-clicking on packaged Java archive, but I provide you with common approach in Java web-development and recommend it.